# How to use custom tile source with local database in OSMdroid offlinemap?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have a local custom tile database in sdcard/external storage, which format looks like below:
(Sorry for not having enough reputation to post pic)

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx8tj.png

[2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXIha.png

[3]https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJeEt.png

Can I use it to be the tile source of the OSM offline map? How?

I'm a newbie of osmdroid, if there's any solution or suggest will be very very helpful, thanks!

---

I only find this offline sample code but I don't know how to change it to load my local custom database.

Android Studio Code:

```
        public static final GeoPoint TAIPEI = new GeoPoint(25.037299, 
        121.565034);

        MapView map;


        @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MAPNIK",ResourceProxy.string.mapnik, 1, 22, 256, ".png", new String[] {"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/"}) {});

        map.setUseDataConnection(false);

        map.setClickable(true);

        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        IMapController mapController = map.getController();

        mapController.setZoom(20);

        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(TAIPEI);

        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to implement custom TileProvider/TileSource and a few more things, see the documentation for map sources: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources and for offline tiles: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles .

Comment: I think you could also look into existing support for [mbtiles](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/19053d1435e8fa4e58b04960b23b0769e99adb66/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/MBTilesFileArchive.java). since mbtiles are actually just a sqlite database with tiles - a different one than you have, but It might act as example. It will take some effort to figure out how things are working together in the library, but it can be done.